# How do I break a large number of subequations into two columns?

Tags: columns, subequations

I have 9, 3x3 matricies that I want to have arranged into two columns so that they do not take up a large, narrow strip in the middle of the page.  This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(0)}_{0}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(1)}_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(1)}_{0}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(1)}_{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{0}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \\
    \vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{-2}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

I was wondering if I could arrange these into two columns so that they do not make a skinny list down the middle of the page?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working example, a complete but small document) which we can compile.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the `multicol` package couldn't be used.  An adjustment to the space inserted at the beginning of the list might be needed.

Comment: Do you want the (sub)equations be numbered?

Answer (score 2):

Based on guessing, without use of `multicol` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{>{$\displaystyle}X<{$}} @{}}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(0)}_{0} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}   \\
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(1)}_{1} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}  \\
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(1)}_{0} & =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}   \\ 
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(1)}_{-1} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}   \\
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{2}& =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned}
    &
    \begin{aligned}[t]
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{1} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}   \\    
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{0} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}   \\
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{-1} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}  \\
\vec{\vec{T}}^{(2)}_{-2} & =
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{aligned}
\end{tabularx}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With some tricks to cover our tracks…

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for context

\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\vec{\vec{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{subequations}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{4em}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}
    \begin{flalign}
    \qquad
    \matr{T}^{(0)}_{0}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(1)}_{1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(1)}_{0}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(1)}_{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(2)}_{2}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    &&
    \end{flalign}
    \begin{flalign}
    \qquad
    \matr{T}^{(2)}_{1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(2)}_{0}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(2)}_{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &&\\
    \matr{T}^{(2)}_{-2}&=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &&
    \end{flalign}
\end{multicols}
\end{subequations}

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

The `kantlipsum` package is used just to provide mock text.

You'll realize the importance of defining `\matr` when you'll decide to change the antiquate notation with a double arrow for a modern one and this will only require changing *one* line of your document.

[image]