# How do I split subequations into two columns

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am wondering if there is a nice way of splitting a set of short subequations into two columns in a otherwise one column document.

My current code looks like this:

```
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:bell_states}
    \begin{alignat}{1}
        \ket{\Phi^+} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{00}+\ket{11}) \label{eq:bell_states:Phi+}\\
        \ket{\Phi^-} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{00}-\ket{11})\label{eq:bell_states:Phi-}\\
        \ket{\Psi^+} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{01}+\ket{10}) \label{eq:bell_states:Psi+}\\
        \ket{\Psi^-} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{01}-\ket{10})\label{eq:bell_states:Psi-}
    \end{alignat}

\end{subequations}
```

Comment: [How do I break a large number of subequations into two columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513503/134144) might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a difference between `alignat{1}` and  `align`. Here's how I would do it:

```
    \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{braket} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{subequations}
    %\label{eq:bell_states}
    \noindent\centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{align}
        \ket{\Phi^+} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{00}+\ket{11}) \label{eq:bell_states:Phi+}\\
        \ket{\Phi^-} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{00}-\ket{11})\label{eq:bell_states:Phi-}
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
    \label{eq:bell_states}
        \begin{align}
        \ket{\Psi^+} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{01}+\ket{10}) \label{eq:bell_states:Psi+r}\\
        \ket{\Psi^-} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket{01}-\ket{10})\label{eq:bell_states:Psi-r}
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}\bigskip
    \end{subequations}

    We see in equations \eqref{eq:bell_states}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had something similar in mind, but I was wondering if there was another way. For some reasons I am not a big fan of minipages. Happy New Year!

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not so many ways for equations. You also might do that with a `tabularx` with two X columns. Happy New Year all the same!